# channel lock error while configuring flume's multiple sources using FILE channels

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

Configuring multiple sources for an agent throwing me lock error using FILE channel. Below is my config file.

```
a1.sources = r1 r2
a1.sinks = k1 k2
a1.channels = c1 c3

#sources
a1.sources.r1.type=netcat
a1.sources.r1.bind=localhost
a1.sources.r1.port=4444

a1.sources.r2.type=exec
a1.sources.r2.command=tail -f /opt/gen_logs/logs/access.log

#sinks
a1.sinks.k1.type=hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path=/flume201
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix=netcat-
a1.sinks.k1.rollInterval=100
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.callTimeout=100000


a1.sinks.k2.type=hdfs
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.path=/flume202
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.filePefix=execCommand-
a1.sinks.k2.rollInterval=100
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.callTimeOut=100000

#channels
a1.channels.c1.type=file
a1.channels.c1.checkpointDir=/home/cloudera/alpha/001
a1.channels.c3.type=file
a1.channels.c3.checkpointDir=/home/cloudera/beta/001

#bind r1 c1 k1
a1.sources.r1.channels=c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel=c1

a1.sources.r2.channels=c3
a1.sinks.k2.channel=c3
```

I am getting below error

```
Channel closed [channel=c3]. Due to java.io.IOException: Cannot lock /home/cloudera/.flume/file-channel/data. The directory is already locked. [channel=c3]
```

But when i am using memory channel. Its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

My gues is that you need to specify different `dataDirs` property for each channel, cause both of them use the default value

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#file-channel)

> By default the File Channel uses paths for checkpoint and data
>   directories that are within the user home as specified above. As a
>   result if you have more than one File Channel instances active within
>   the agent, only one will be able to lock the directories and cause the
>   other channel initialization to fail. It is therefore necessary that
>   you provide explicit paths to all the configured channels, preferably
>   on different disks.

The configuration for the channels should be,

```
#channels
a1.channels.c1.type=file
a1.channels.c1.checkpointDir=/home/cloudera/alpha/001
a1.channels.c1.dataDirs=/mnt/alpha_data/

a1.channels.c3.type=file
a1.channels.c3.checkpointDir=/home/cloudera/beta/001
a1.channels.c3.dataDirs=/mnt/beta_data/
```

The `dataDirs` property defaults to `/home/user/.flume/file-channel/data` path.