# data channel lock error while configuring flume with multiple channels

Tags: flume-ng

I have tried to  fan out the flow from one source to two channels.Also I specified different dataDirs and checkpointDirs properties for each channel as in the [channel lock error while configuring flume's multiple sources using FILE channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983979/channel-lock-error-while-configuring-flumes-multiple-sources-using-file-channel) question.I have used a multiplexing channel selector. I have get the following error.

```
18/08/23 16:21:37 **ERROR file.FileChannel: Failed to start the file channel** [channel=fileChannel1_2]
java.io.IOException: Cannot lock /root/.flume/file-channel/data. The directory is already locked. [channel=fileChannel1_2]
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.lock(Log.java:1169)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.<init>(Log.java:336)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.<init>(Log.java:76)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log$Builder.build(Log.java:276)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.start(FileChannel.java:281)
    at unAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) .....
```

My configuration file as follws.

```
agent1.sinks=hdfs-sink1_1 hdfs-sink1_2 

agent1.sources=source1_1

agent1.channels=fileChannel1_1 fileChannel1_2

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.type=file

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.checkpointDir=/home/Flume/alpha/001
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.dataDir=/mnt/alpha_data/
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.checkpointOnClose=true

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.dataOnClose=true

agent1.sources.source1_1.type=spooldir

agent1.sources.source1_1.spoolDir=/home/ABC/
agent1.sources.source1_1.recursiveDirectorySearch=true
agent1.sources.source1_1.fileSuffix=.COMPLETED

agent1.sources.source1_1.basenameHeader = true

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.type=hdfs

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.path=hdfs://10.44.209.44:9000/flume_sink/CA

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.batchSize=1000

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollSize=268435456

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollInterval=0

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollCount=50000000

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.fileType=DataStream

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.writeFormat=Text

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp=false

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.type=file

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.capacity=200000
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.transactionCapacity=1000
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.checkpointDir=/home/Flume/beta/001
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.dataDir=/mnt/beta_data/
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.checkpointOnClose=true
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.dataOnClose=true

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.type=hdfs

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.path=hdfs://10.44.209.44:9000/flume_sink/AZ

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.batchSize=1000

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.rollSize=268435456

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.rollInterval=0

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.rollCount=50000000

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.fileType=DataStream

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.writeFormat=Text

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp=false

agent1.sources.source1_1.channels=fileChannel1_1 fileChannel1_2

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.channel=fileChannel1_1

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.channel=fileChannel1_2

agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.type=multiplexing
agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.header=basenameHeader
agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.mapping.CA=fileChannel1_1
agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.mapping.AZ=fileChannel1_2
```

can someone give any solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set a channel for default property in multiplexing selector

> agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.default=fileChannel1_1

Comment: Thank you. When selector is default, it replicate all the events to both channel. What I need is multiplex the data flow into two channels. According to the Apache Flume documentation Flume multiplex the events according to the event header. To do this I should add file names to the event header. How can I do that? Should I use Flume Interceptor? Are there any in built filename interceptors in Flume?

Comment: **fileHeader** and **fileHeaderKey** properties should add the file name to the event header

Comment: I used fileHeaderKey anf fileHeader properties as follows. agent1.sources.source1_1.fileHeader=true agent1.sources.source1_1.fileHeaderKey=file Then what should be the agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.header=???

Comment: agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.header=file
But the header will contain the absolute file path
So mapping should specify the file path
agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.mapping.ABSOLUTE_FILE_PATH=fileChannel1_1

Comment: I want to do mapping using file name not using the file path. Is it possible to do mapping with file name by using above agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.mapping.ABSOLUTE_FILE_PATH=fileChannel1_1  command???

Comment: If the number of files are few you can define each file in separate source and use static interceptor to add the filename in header
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#static-interceptor

Comment: I have large amount of files. So above method is not suitable. I want to add file name to the each event's header. Can you give me an another solution?

Comment: Can you try **basenameHeader** and **basenameHeaderKey** properties

Comment: I used them. agent1.sources.source1_1.basenameHeader = true
agent1.sources.source1_1.basenameHeaderKey = basename Then what should be the agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.header=???

Comment: agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.header=basename

Comment: It also didn't work. My configuration file is in the below answer. Can you please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Data channel lock error was corrected. But still could't do the multiplexing. Code as follows.

```
agent1.sinks=hdfs-sink1_1 hdfs-sink1_2 hdfs-sink1_3

agent1.sources=source1_1

agent1.channels=fileChannel1_1 fileChannel1_2 fileChannel1_3

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.type=file

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.capacity=200000

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.transactionCapacity=1000

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.checkpointDir=/home/Flume/alpha/001

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.dataDirs=/home/Flume/alpha_data

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.checkpointOnClose=true

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.dataOnClose=true



agent1.sources.source1_1.type=spooldir

agent1.sources.source1_1.spoolDir=/home/ABC/

agent1.sources.source1_1.recursiveDirectorySearch=true

agent1.sources.source1_1.fileSuffix=.COMPLETED

agent1.sources.source1_1.basenameHeader = true

agent1.sources.source1_1.basenameHeaderKey = basename



agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.type=hdfs

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.path=hdfs://10.44.209.44:9000/flume_sink/CA

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.batchSize=1000

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollSize=268435456

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollInterval=0

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollCount=50000000

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.fileType=DataStream

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.writeFormat=Text

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp=false


agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.type=file

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.capacity=200000

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.transactionCapacity=1000

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.checkpointDir=/home/Flume/beta/001

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.dataDirs=/home/Flume/beta_data

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.checkpointOnClose=true

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.dataOnClose=true



agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.type=hdfs

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.path=hdfs://10.44.209.44:9000/flume_sink/AZ

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.batchSize=1000

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.rollSize=268435456

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.rollInterval=0

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.rollCount=50000000

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.fileType=DataStream

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.writeFormat=Text

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp=false

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.type=file

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.capacity=200000

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.transactionCapacity=10

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.checkpointDir=/home/Flume/gamma/001

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.dataDirs=/home/Flume/gamma_data

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.checkpointOnClose=true

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.dataOnClose=true


agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.type=hdfs

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.path=hdfs://10.44.209.44:9000/flume_sink/KT

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.batchSize=1000

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.rollSize=268435456

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.rollInterval=0

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.rollCount=50000000

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.fileType=DataStream

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.writeFormat=Text

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp=false



agent1.sources.source1_1.channels=fileChannel1_1 fileChannel1_2 fileChannel1_3

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.channel=fileChannel1_1

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.channel=fileChannel1_2

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.channel=fileChannel1_3



agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.type=replicating

agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.header=basename

agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.mapping.CA=fileChannel1_1

agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.mapping.AZ=fileChannel1_2

agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.default=fileChannel1_3
```